# TCP open socket from port that's already used for listening

Tags: networking, network-programming, port, tcp

Suppose I have a TCP Server(A) listening on port 8001.

Now, I want to open a TCP Socket to Server(B) from Server(A) using local port 8001. So that, Server(B) will see connection from Server(A) from port 8001.

Is it possible ? Can I use a port for outgoing connection that's already used for listening incoming connections.

Comment: Why? What do you care what the source port is?

Comment: I am writing a p2p app. I care about what is source port because if I connect to someone and disconnect. They should be able to connect back to me later. They won't be able to connect to me unless they know what port I am listening. That means, I will have to explicitly tell other nodes the port I am listening. I don't want to do that. And use same port for both incoming and outgoing connections.

Comment: If you disconnect, then you are no longer using that port. In any case, the port is part of the original connection, and the other host could save that port number, but the hosts will still need to negotiate a new connection.

Comment: Example: 
Node 1 listening on port 8001. Node 2 listening on port 8001. N1 opens socket to N2, with local/source port 8001 ( N1:8001 -> N1:8001 ). N1 disconnects the connection. N2 knows last connection source port was 8001, So it connects back (N2:8001 -> N1:8001). Nodes will keep listening to port 8001. Node will terminate only outgoing connections.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the port number is. N2 can save the port number from the first connection, and it can use that port number to reconnect, even if the port number is different than its own port number.

Comment: Right. But only if, N1 makes the first connection from a port which it's already listening. Which I am asking if is possible.

Comment: You seem to be confusing two different things. Why can't a device be listening on a port for which it has connections? A web server listens on port 80, but still has multiple connections on that port. A connection consists of the source and destination IP and TCP addresses combined, so each connection is unique. You can listen on any port (TCP address) but till have connections using that port because the connections will be unique base on the IP and TCP addresses from the other end.

Comment: Maybe I am confusing or maybe I am not able to convey my question well. I will try giving another example. A webserver listens on port 80, many clients can connect with it on that port. Now, suppose, **webserver want to** connect to another server, such that the other server see source port as 80. (at the same time, it keeps listening on port 80)

Comment: Like, in udp, I can send and listen on same port. Sent packet will show source port on other machine same as the port I am listening to on .

Comment: You are creating a different connection. The connections are unique because they consist of four different values: the source and destination IP and TCP addresses. The connection to a different server will be unique among all the connections that the server has. Don't confuse the TCP port with a connection.

Comment: I also see no reason why the server could not contact the other server with an ephemeral port. The other server should know that the first server has a well-known port listening. You should establish a port for listening, and then you can use ephemeral ports to create the connection, as you should.

Comment: Your client needs two things: (1) a listening socket and (2) a connected socket. It can send the port number of the listening socket via the connected socket. You don't need to control the outbound port of the connected socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that: `socket` followed by `setsockopt(SO_REUSEPORT)` and then `bind`.

`man socket(7)`:

> **SO_REUSEPORT** (since Linux 3.9)
>
> Permits multiple `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` sockets to be bound to an  identical socket address. This option must be set on each  socket (including the first socket) prior to calling `bind(2)` on  the socket. To prevent port hijacking, all of the processes  binding to the same address must have the same effective UID.  This option can be employed with both TCP and UDP sockets.

Here is a working example that has two sockets bound to the same address and port 127.0.0.1:2222. One socket is a listening server socket, another is a client successfully making a connection to 127.0.0.1:22 (ssh):

```
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int socket_and_bind() {
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(-1 == s)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "socket");

    int flag = 1;
    if(-1 == setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &flag, sizeof flag))
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "setsockopt(SO_REUSEPORT)");

    sockaddr_in sa = {};
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    sa.sin_port = htons(2222);
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if(-1 == bind(s, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sa), sizeof sa))
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "bind");

    return s;
}

void server(int s) {
    int c = accept(s, nullptr, nullptr);
    if(-1 == c)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "accept");
    close(c);
}

void client(int s) {
    sockaddr_in sa = {};
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    sa.sin_port = htons(22);
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if(-1 == connect(s, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sa), sizeof sa))
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "connect");

    char buf;
    if(1 != recv(s, &buf, sizeof buf, 0))
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "recv");

    printf("connected\n");
}

int main() {
    int s1 = socket_and_bind();
    if(-1 == listen(s1, 1))
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "listen");

    int s2 = socket_and_bind();

    std::thread t1(server, s1);
    std::thread t2(client, s2);
    t2.join();
    t1.detach();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

One thing that is broken in Linux is connecting from an addr:port to the same:addr port.

Comment: Not with TCP. This option only works for UDP sockets.

Comment: @EJP You are wrong. I added a working example to demonstrate that.